# How to make sure my PHP app wont be distibuted?

Tags: php

I have made an appointment management php app for a department of an institution. They insist to keep the app in their server, because the database is holding sensitive informations, and they don`t want to hand it for a 3rd party.

If they give my app for the other departments or make a copy and run it on other institution's server, i would never know about it, which i really don`t want.

Can i somehow give them a really hard time to make changes on my app and make it impossible (or at least difficult) to move to other servers without my permission ?

I really appreciate any kind of idea.

Comment: You can't. Once they have the code it's beyond your control. You can use an obfuscation tool, but these can be cracked, it just increases the difficulty by a marginal amount. The best approach is to add telemetry to your application to make it phone home once in a while to validate license codes. That way you can track deployed instances. While that license tracking can be removed, you can try and sneak it in places that people wouldn't think to look, so to a casual observer it's not present.

Comment: The best defense here is an iron-clad contract with penalties for misuse spelled out in abundantly clear terms. A lawyer familiar with software licensing and IP protection can help here.

Comment: What @tadman said. This should be treated as a contractual/legal situation, not a technological one. Tell them it's going to cost more that way, too.

Comment: I understand the legal point, but as i mentioned, i would never know if they distribute it, because it would run in a local enviroment in institutes where i dont have privileges just to walk in and ask around if they are using my app or not. Obfuscation is way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as perfect protection, given enough time any copy protection can be broken. That said the most universally accepted solution to this is [IonCube](http://www.ioncube.com/). If you want to lock it to the system, perhaps check some hardware thing and hard code it in, such as the system's IP and/or MAC address.

Most hosts are happy to run the [IonCube](http://www.ioncube.com/) extension and it is pre-packaged with cPanel hosting environments and the like.

Answer (score 2):

You could make some services on your own server, called by your scripts, like SaaS and that would probably be the best protection - you could then guard the calls to the services using some tokens, oAuth, whatever...